# синхронизация файлов по sftp

Tags: git, ssh, sftp, brackets

В команде 2 разработчика со слабыми компьютерами(локально разварачивать сайт не получается очень тормозит). Оба работают на сайте через sftp с разными файлами.
хочу упростить разработку

сейчас мой процесс налажен таким образом.
есть локальная копия сайта, файлы которые синхронизируются редактором Brackets по sftp.
[image: плагин в редакторе brackets]

я редактирую файл, он автоматом улетает на сайт, коммит делаю прямо с того же редактора в 2 клика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но столкнулся с проблемами:

1. когда второй разработчик меняет файлы на сервере, он не меняются
   у меня локально
2. когда я делаю коммит локально, он не делается на
   сервере, изза этого приходится пушить в репозиторий и потом на
   сервере пулить, но при этом сделать чек аут всех файлов на сервере
   (крайне не удобно)
3. делать пуш из сервера тоже не удобно, так как
   приходится вводить логин и пароль в Putty

Идеальный для меня бы вариант был делать пуш, пул и коммит прямо из сервера, каким нибудь визуальным окружением, например тот же Git-Brackets, или git gui
Через bash панель очень не удобно работать

Будьте любезны, поделится своим советом, как работаете вы?

Comment: Мы работает по-правильному: не правим файлы на живом сервере, а используем локальные машины разработчиков как dev-окружение. Чего и вам искренне желаем: найти нормальную контору, где руководство понимает, что разработчикам нужны нормальные машины, где построен более грамотный рабочий процесс, а не используются допотопные технологии из прошлого века. Меньше изучать костылестроение -- больше времени на улучшение квалификации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал вам настроить rsync + lsyncd демон и не привязываться к IDE. Настроить его нужно таким образом, чтобы ваша локальная рутовая директория проекта синхронизировалась с сервером. Вот приблизительно то, что я имею в [виду](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-mirror-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps-with-lsyncd)